# File not found when deployed on server, but works fine when app is tested locally

Tags: python, flask, web, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I've been creating a simple invoicing web app using Python and Flask. One of its functionalities is that it automatically generates the PDF of the invoice once and sends it to the designated email address. Here is the route and function for that specific part: (Which is the only route and function I'm running into errors with)

```
@forms.route("/sendasemail/<int:id>", methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def sendasemail(id):
    order = Order.query.get(id)
    products = order.products
    rendered = render_template("invoice.html", order = order, products = products)   
    save_location = url_for('static', filename=f'Order_{id}.pdf') 
    pdf = pdfkit.from_string(rendered, save_location)

    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg['Subject'] = f"Order Form No. {id}"
    msg['From'] = 'DESIGNATED EMAIL'
    if current_user.username == 'USERNAME':
        msg['To'] = 'DESIGNATED_EMAIL'
    else:
        msg['To'] = 'DESIGNATED_EMAIL'
    msg.set_content(f"Hi, \n\nKindly find Order Form No.{id} attached to this email.\n\nRegards,\nShibam S.P. Trading")  

    with open(f'Order_{id}.pdf', 'rb') as f:
        file_data = f.read()
        file_name = f.name

    msg.add_attachment(file_data, maintype='application', subtype='octet-stream', filename=file_name)
    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as smtp:
        smtp.login('DESIGNATED_EMAIL', 'DESIGNATED_PASSWORD')
        smtp.send_message(msg)

    os.unlink(f'Order_{id}.pdf')
    flash("Email sent!", "success")
    return render_template('show_data.html', order = order, products = products)
```

This snippet of code depends on the wkhtmltopdf and PDFKit libraries to function. When I run this code locally, it works perfectly fine. However, when I try running the same function within the application deployed on a production server, it throws an Internal Server Error. I think it might be because the PDF file, once created, cannot be found by the program due to some directory restructuring that I'm missing out on or plainly don't understand.

Comment: What is the error message in the logfile?

Comment: @Dauros I checked the log file in var/log/[myfolder] but it doesn't seem to reflect the code changes I'd made before I posted here on Stackoverflow. If you have any suggestion as to where I can find a recently updated log file, it would be great. I'm kinda new to this and have been following Corey Schafer's tutorials on YouTube for deploying the application. Anyway, here are the errors from the logfile: [link](https://pastebin.com/5z5TKT19)

Answer (score 0):

In the `save_location = url_for('static', filename=f'Order_{id}.pdf')` you create an absolute URL path, e.g. `/static/Order_1.pdf` instead of a local relative file path, like `Order_1.pdf`. But later in the script you use the local file path.

So the quick fix is just to use the local file path for `save_location` as well:

```
save_location = f'Order_{id}.pdf'
```

This assumes that the root directory of the Flask app is writable by the process. If not, you have to use a temporary directory, e.g. `/tmp/` or an equivalent on your production server and update each file path in the script accordingly.